# What is right way to store and retrieve sensitive and non-sensitive constants?

Tags: scala

My objective is to understand how to include sensitive constants/secrets (eg. api token) and non-sensitive constants (eg. api route) in my code.

Example for a sensitive constant:

```
val apiToken = "Hushhhh!"
```

Example for a non-sensitive constant:

```
val happyUsersEndpoint = "https://happy.foo.io/v1/users"
```

My questions are:

1. In which part of my folder structure should I store non-sensitive constants?
2. Is there a safe way to store sensitive constants in my code? If not, what is the right way to reference them from outside within my code?

To my understanding, there are ways to do that in Java-ish code, but I am mainly looking for ways that fit well into Scala code (if possible).

Comment: This is really a design question general to any application, not particular to Scala. You can find a lot of resources in the internet explaining techniques of how to manage secrets. Also, as Artem said, this is very dependant of your technology stack, specially the operational stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not be in the source code and in the VCS repo.

It should be a part of the deployment/operation process.

You can use some sort of a config or retrieve it from env variables. Which is better depends on your stack. Is it a docker? Is it a Play or something from typelevel stack?

For each situation, there are would be a different appropriate method. For example:

- For Play you can use just play config files in HOCON format.
- In typelevel you have [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig).
- For docker installation, it is better to use env.
- If you have a simple zero dependency console app - I suggest adding command line args with needed properties.
- For a simple app without play, cats and docker - just pick a lightweight simple library.